# help merging perl code routines together for file processing

Tags: perl, foreach, while-loop, fileparsing

I need some perl help in putting these (2) processes/code to work together. I was able to get them working individually to test, but I need help bringing them together especially with using the loop constructs. I'm not sure if I should go with foreach..anyways the code is below.

Also, any best practices would be great too as I'm learning this language. Thanks for your help.

Here's the process flow I am looking for:

- read a directory
- look for a particular file
- use the file name to strip out some key information to create a newly processed file
- process the input file
- create the newly processed file for each input file read (if i read in 10, I create 10 new files)

Part 1:

```
my $target_dir = "/backups/test/";
opendir my $dh, $target_dir or die "can't opendir $target_dir: $!";
while (defined(my $file = readdir($dh))) {
    next if ($file =~ /^\.+$/);
    #Get filename attributes
    if ($file =~ /^foo(\d{3})\.name\.(\w{3})-foo_p(\d{1,4})\.\d+.csv$/) {
      print "$1\n";
      print "$2\n";
      print "$3\n";
    }
    print "$file\n";
}
```

Part 2:

```
use strict;
use Digest::MD5 qw(md5_hex);
#Create new file
open (NEWFILE, ">/backups/processed/foo$1.name.$2-foo_p$3.out") || die "cannot create file";
my $data = '';
my $line1 = <>;
chomp $line1;
my @heading = split /,/, $line1;
my ($sep1, $sep2, $eorec) = ( "^A", "^E", "^D");
while (<>)
{
    my $digest = md5_hex($data);
    chomp;
    my (@values) = split /,/;
    my $extra = "__mykey__$sep1$digest$sep2" ;
    $extra .= "$heading[$_]$sep1$values[$_]$sep2" for (0..scalar(@values));
    $data .= "$extra$eorec"; 
    print NEWFILE "$data";
}
#print $data;
close (NEWFILE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've bashed your two code fragments together (making the second a `sub` that the first calls for each matching file) and, if I understood your description of the objective correctly, this should do what you want.  Comments on style and syntax are inline:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

# - Never forget these!
use strict;
use warnings;

use Digest::MD5 qw(md5_hex);

my $target_dir = "/backups/test/";
opendir my $dh, $target_dir or die "can't opendir $target_dir: $!";
while (defined(my $file = readdir($dh))) {
    # Parens on postfix "if" are optional; I prefer to omit them
    next if $file =~ /^\.+$/;
    if ($file =~ /^foo(\d{3})\.name\.(\w{3})-foo_p(\d{1,4})\.\d+.csv$/) {
        process_file($file, $1, $2, $3);
    }
    print "$file\n";
}

sub process_file {
    my ($orig_name, $foo_x, $name_x, $p_x) = @_;

    my $new_name = "/backups/processed/foo$foo_x.name.$name_x-foo_p$p_x.out";

    # - From your description of the task, it sounds like we actually want to
    #   read from the found file, not from <>, so opening it here to read
    # - Better to use lexical ("my") filehandle and three-arg form of open
    # - "or" has lower operator precedence than "||", so less chance of
    #   things being grouped in the wrong order (though either works here)
    # - Including $! in the error will tell why the file open failed
    open my $in_fh, '<', $orig_name or die "cannot read $orig_name: $!";
    open(my $out_fh, '>', $new_name) or die "cannot create $new_name: $!";

    my $data  = '';
    my $line1 = <$in_fh>;
    chomp $line1;
    my @heading = split /,/, $line1;
    my ($sep1, $sep2, $eorec) = ("^A", "^E", "^D");
    while (<$in_fh>) {
        chomp;
        my $digest   = md5_hex($data);
        my (@values) = split /,/;
        my $extra    = "__mykey__$sep1$digest$sep2";
        $extra .= "$heading[$_]$sep1$values[$_]$sep2"
          for (0 .. scalar(@values));
        # - Useless use of double quotes removed on next two lines
        $data .= $extra . $eorec;
        #print $out_fh $data;
    }
    # - Moved print to output file to here (where it will print the complete
    #   output all at once) rather than within the loop (where it will print
    #   all previous lines each time a new line is read in) to prevent
    #   duplicate output records.  This could also be achieved by printing
    #   $extra inside the loop.  Printing $data at the end will be slightly
    #   faster, but requires more memory; printing $extra within the loop and
    #   getting rid of $data entirely would require less memory, so that may
    #   be the better option if you find yourself needing to read huge input
    #   files.
    print $out_fh $data;

    # - $in_fh and $out_fh will be closed automatically when it goes out of
    #   scope at the end of the block/sub, so there's no real point to
    #   explicitly closing it unless you're going to check whether the close
    #   succeeded or failed (which can happen in odd cases usually involving
    #   full or failing disks when writing; I'm not aware of any way that
    #   closing a file open for reading can fail, so that's just being left
    #   implicit)
    close $out_fh or die "Failed to close file: $!";
}
```

Disclaimer: `perl -c` reports that this code is syntactically valid, but it is otherwise untested.

Comment: thank you! its working well now. Its a good example for me. I wasn't sure how to properly use a file open and using the `<>`.

Comment: i'm actually getting some dup records on the outfile. If I add a $print $data after the `close $out_fh` line, I can see it will print the correct number of recs. Let me know if i'm missing something. thanks.

Comment: @jdamae: Ah, yes. You said the code in the question worked (as far as it went), so I didn't look at it that closely. You should only print `$extra` (the latest line) to `$out_fh` at the end of the loop, not `$data` (all lines read from the file so far). I'll also edit my answer to fix this.

Comment: @jdamae: OK, so I changed my mind and fixed the duplication problem a different way than I said I would... but I also added a comment in the code explaining why I chose to do it the other way and what the relative benefits of each are.

Answer (score 3):

You are using an old-style of Perl programming. I recommend you to use functions and CPAN modules (http://search.cpan.org). Perl pseudocode:

```
use Modern::Perl;
# use... 

sub get_input_files {
  # return an array of files (@)
}

sub extract_file_info {
   # takes the file name and returs an array of values (filename attrs)
}

sub process_file {
   # reads the input file, takes the previous attribs and build the output file
}


my @ifiles = get_input_files;
foreach my $ifile(@ifiles) {
   my @attrs = extract_file_info($ifile);
   process_file($ifile, @attrs);
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Yes, it does. Moreover, it works better than any other programming style.

Comment: ok, long term i can see that, but would like to get this working if i can. thanks.